# I sent money to myself with Bisq, but I have not recieved it?

Tags: address

I sent money to my own wallet address, from my wallet on Bisq.

I did not receive the money, even though the payment is completed and has a check mark. In transaction, it shows just a withdrawn, without a received funds transaction.

I have not received the amount I sent to myself.

The reason I did it was to reset the wallet address for privacy (they don't let you get a new address without using it).

Comment: Maybe someone already had the same problem and solved it? --https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=+not+received+is%3Aq

Comment: Did you check if the transaction is confirmed? Please check it with your favorite explorer

Comment: It is completely confirmed. The check mark means that it is confirmed in Bisq right? I don't know if other people had this issue (no bisq).